# Python Shift values in one column based on Nan or boolean in other column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, boolean, nan

Thank you so much for your help! It is great to have access to such a great community :)
**edited**

I'm desperately trying to solve this for two days now, so I really hope to get some help from you all.

I have a table that looks like this:

| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| This |  | 1 |
|  | Das | 2 |
| is |  | 3 |
|  | ist | 4 |
| a |  | 5 |
|  | ein | 6 |
| not_translated |  | 7 |
| text | Text | 8 |
| , |  | 9 |
|  |  | 10 |
|  | , | 11 |
| and | und | 12 |
| so |  | 13 |
|  | so | 14 |
| . |  | 15 |
|  | . | 16 |

I now want that every translation in ColumnB is shifted one line up when there is nothing written in Column A (so that "This" and "Das" is in the same row), but stays in the same row when there is text in ColumnA (as in "text" and "Text"). So the result I want to achieve is:

| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| This | Das | 1 |
| is | ist | 3 |
| a | ein | 5 |
| not_translated |  | 7 |
| text | Text | 8 |
| , | , | 9 |
| and | und | 12 |
| so | so | 13 |
| . | . | 15 |

What I've tried so far is to use a boolean, which hasn't worked out:

```
df1['bool'] = (df1['ColumnA'].isnull())
if df1['bool']:
    df1['ColumnB'].shift(periods=-1)
else:
    df1['ColumnB']
```

and also by using the np.where:

```
df1["ColumnB"] = np.where((df1["ColumnA"].isnull()), df1["ColumnB"].shift(periods=-1), df1["ColumnB"])
```

It would be perfect to shift up the translation in ColumnB to the next row of ColumnA with text (this was my original try, but unfortunately it didn't work out).
Thank you very much for your help and efforts so far!

Comment: You'll need to loop over the rows of the dataframe, store the previous and the current row in a variable and then construct a new dataframe row by row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edited according to change of requirement:*

**An approach without using looping:**

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['ColumnA', 'ColumnB'], how='all').copy()
m = df['ColumnB'].shift(-1).notna() & df['ColumnA'].shift(-1).isna() & df['ColumnB'].isna()
df.loc[m, 'ColumnB'] = df['ColumnB'].shift(-1)
df = df.dropna(subset=['ColumnA'])
```

**Data input:**

```
           ColumnA ColumnB  ColumnC
0             This     NaN        1
1              NaN     Das        2
2               is     NaN        3
3              NaN     ist        4
4                a     NaN        5
5              NaN     ein        6
6   not_translated     NaN        7
7             text    Text        8
8                ,     NaN        9
9              NaN     NaN       10
10             NaN       ,       11
11             and     und       12
12              so     NaN       13
13             NaN      so       14
14               .     NaN       15
15             NaN       .       16
```

**Result:**

```
           ColumnA ColumnB  ColumnC
0             This     Das        1
2               is     ist        3
4                a     ein        5
6   not_translated     NaN        7
7             text    Text        8
8                ,       ,        9
11             and     und       12
12              so      so       13
14               .       .       15
```

Comment: Thank you, but it unfortunately doesn't work with my updated table (cf. edit in the original question):  it then moves the "." in ColumnB to the row with "not_translated" in Column A.

Comment: Works perfectly! And is very concise! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You are using `ColumnA` as the subject of your logical statement. There is an easier approach to this:

1. If `ColumnB` is null, use the row below it. If not, keep its original value.
2. If `ColumnA` is 'not_translated', keep null in `ColumnB`.
3. Drop rows where `ColumnA` is null.

In code:

```py
# If B is null, take next value. Otherwise, keep value.
df['ColumnB_new'] = np.where(df['ColumnB'].notna(), df['ColumnB'], df['ColumnB'].shift(-1))

# If A is 'not_tranlsated', leave null
df['ColumnB_new'] = np.where(df['ColumnA'].eq('not_translated'), np.nan, df['ColumnB_new'])

# Result
df = df.loc[df['ColumnA'].notna(), ['ColumnA','ColumnB_new']]
print(df)

          ColumnA ColumnB_new
0            This         Das
2              is         ist
4               a         ein
6  not_translated         NaN
7            text        text
8               .           .
```

Comment: This does not produce the right results when there is one row in Column A that is not translated in Column B (and therefore should stay empty) - please have a look at my edit above.

Comment: And I've just realised that it writes two times my ColumnB (so the translation).

Comment: Yes, good, but it produces two times "Text" in Column B (this is the problem that I had with my old code too), so it produces: row1: not_translated | Text , row2: text | Text

Comment: I think you haven't added the "not_translated" row that I've added in my Edit above, have you?

Comment: I edited my answer to make it work with edit #1. However, I'm a little lost with all the edits. Can you delete all the previous versions of the table from your post so that only the latest one remains?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question above, I hope, it is clearer now!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach you could try:

**Code:**

```
df = df.dropna(axis=0, subset=['ColumnA', 'ColumnB'], how='all').reset_index(drop=True)

idxs=df[df['ColumnA'].isna() & df['ColumnB'].notna()].index.tolist()

for i in idxs:
    df['ColumnB'].iloc[i-1] = df['ColumnB'].iloc[i]
    df['ColumnB'].iloc[i] = np.NaN

df = df.dropna(axis=0, subset=['ColumnA', 'ColumnB'], how='all').reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

**Input:**

```
           ColumnA ColumnB  ColumnC
0             This     NaN        1
1              NaN     Das        2
2               is     NaN        3
3              NaN     ist        4
4                a     NaN        5
5              NaN     ein        6
6   not_translated     NaN        7
7             text    Text        8
8                ,     NaN        9
9              NaN     NaN       10
10             NaN       ,       11
11             and     und       12
12              so     NaN       13
13             NaN      so       14
14               .     NaN       15
15             NaN       .       16
```

**Output:**

```
          ColumnA ColumnB  ColumnC
0            This     Das        1
1              is     ist        3
2               a     ein        5
3  not_translated     NaN        7
4            text    Text        8
5               ,       ,        9
6             and     und       12
7              so      so       13
8               .       .       15
```

**Explanation:**

1. Find indices where `ColumnA` is `Nan` but `ColumnB` is not
2. For each of those indices replace the `Nan` value in the previous row of `ColumnB` with that in current row
3. Make the value of the current row of `ColumnB` `Nan`
4. Call `dropna` to drop unnecessary rows

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful! Yet, unfortunately some of the rows are more complicated and sometimes there are rows in ColumnA that have no translation in ColumnB. With your approach, they are simply erased. I'll edit the question above to clarify my point.

Comment: @athelas ok please do update the question

Comment: @athelas I've updated the answer to check values of `ColumnA`, try it now

Comment: @athelas updated my answer this should work with your new input

Comment: Unfortunately it again erases the row with "not_translated" (so the one that only exists in ColumnA). But I've now updated the dropna-command to df = df.dropna(axis=0, subset = ['ColumnA','ColumnB'], how = 'all'), and now it keeps all rows! I'll try now with my real dataset.

Comment: @athelas that might not be my latest edit, see my output it keeps `not_translated`

Comment: @athelas did you try it, it seems to be giving the correct output

Comment: Yes, you're right, it works fine with my test script, but when I try to implement it to my larger script, I get an 'IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds' and I don't know how  to handle this.

Comment: I think I understand the problem now. My original dataset has more columns, so I first drop all rows where ColumnA and ColumnB are NAN. Perhaps is "idxs=df[df['ColumnA'].isna()].index.tolist()" therefore saving an index to list, which is not fitting anymore after having deleted several rows? Do you have an idea about this?

Comment: @athelas yes this occurs when the value of `i` is beyond the length of the dataframe. You can drop the rows last like in my code.

Comment: @athelas try the new method I added a dummy column

Comment: That is a really good idea and it works perfectly with most of the datasets, BUT unfortunately there are some datasets where there are some rows where the translation in ColumnB is two lines below the text in ColumnA , and those rows are simply deleted with this method. I'm sorry, it is really a complicated case, but I appreciate your help very much!!

Comment: I've edited my question above to clarify my new problem

Comment: @athelas ok lets `dropna` twice, the updated answer works for the latest input

Comment: Ah, reset_index looks very much like the solution! I'll be back at work on Friday and will come back to you after having tested it there with my data! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: works perfectly well, thank you so much! SeaBean's answer is even more concise, so I've chosen his answer - but yours is delivering the right results as well.